# Java array list printing

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to use an ArrayList of type Character in which I use integers. The code runs without any error but when printing I obtain:

```
[5, 9, 4, 6, 2]
[5, 9, 7, 6, 2]
[9, ?, ?, ?]
```

The third array being printed is after a call to method prime.

```
//Write a method which takes an ArrayList of integers and for each element in the list checks 
//primality, if a number is prime remove it from the ArrayList and if it is not set it to its 
squared value.

public static boolean isPrime(int n){
    for (int i = 2 ; i < n ; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false; 
        }
    }
    return true; 
}

public static void prime(ArrayList<Character> A){
    for (int i = 0 ; i<A.size(); i++){
        if (isPrime(A.get(i))){
            A.remove(i);
        } else {
            A.set(i, (char) Math.pow(A.get(i), 2));
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Character> A = new ArrayList<Character>();
    A.add('5');
    A.add('9');
    A.add('4');
    A.add('6');
    A.add('2');
    A.add('1');
    removeChar(A, '1');
    System.out.println(A);
    replacement(A, '4', '7');
    System.out.println(A);
    prime(A);
    System.out.println(A);
}
```

Comment: `(char) Math.pow(A.get(i), 2)` is squaring the character code at `i`. If you want to square the value the character represents (ex, 2 for '2' and not 50) use `Character.getNumericValue(A.get(i))`.

Comment: Also, `for (int i = 0 ; i<A.size(); i++){` You modify the size of the list when you call `remove()`. You can iterate over the list backwards instead.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to work with numbers, so why use `ArrayList<Character>` and not a `ArrayList<Integer>`?